Why doesn't large select query return any value in ksql?
I have a fairly large query in ksqldb where all the different columns of the query do work, but when I combine them all together I don't get any result. I don't get any feedback telling me why there is no results either.
The query I run is a simple query from one stream, the only thing I do is manipulating some values. If I do a plain SELECT * from the same stream it works, but not when I recreate different structs to fix naming. Are there any limitations on how many operations that can be made in a ksql stream?
